# How To Detect Which Cells Are Merged In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, merge, formatting, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

While trying to remove duplicate phone numbers from a relatively large list I recently combined, Google Sheets presented me with this error message:

> **There was a problem.**
>   Your selection contains a merged cell. To remove duplicates, all cells must contain the same number of rows and columns.

The formula I used to test and try to expose merged cells within Google sheets was:

```
=if(columns(A2:F2) = 6, "True", "False")
```

But this always returned `true` Because even though the cells may be merged they are still considered individual cells.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to discover and sort out these cells in Google Sheets. [Excel used to have a very simple way of doing it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-merged-cells-d02b2a5a-a08d-4641-8d4d-b3f233daca2c) but has since removed the functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you have such an option you can use Conditional Formatting to check for merged cells like:

```
=MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0
```

[image]

where you can immediately spot merged cells where the color pattern is interrupted

---

in the same manner you can use this formula for rows:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

[image]

---

or you can play with scripts to find merged cells: **https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753230**

Comment: This solution worked but wasn't exactly efficient for a ton of data. Scripts may be the only answer for now, but I hope sheets will build this functionality in soon!

Comment: @player0 Does the number 2 indicate the number of cells that have been merged? Is it possible to unmerge with a single formula?

Comment: @TipVisor no. number 2 indicates "every 2nd column" to be painted. unmerge with a single formula is not possible but there is a shortcut key that will reset all formatting on selected cells https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j0gO.png

Answer (score 1):

Custom formula

```
function isMerge(sheetName, a1Notation) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(a1Notation);

  var merges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < range.getHeight(); i++)
  {
    var merge = range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1).isPartOfMerge();
    merges.push(merge);    
  }
  return merges;
}
```

Usage:

1. Paste the code above to the Editor: menu Tools > Script Editor...
2. Save Project
3. Use as usual formula: `=isMerge(sheetName, a1Notation)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can copy and paste the column somewhere, for example creating an extra column next to it.
You can then create a new column. You can run increasing numbers in both and subtract each cell from each other. If the result is not 0, then cells have been merged.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and found a hack - ctrl+shift+down button to select all the data in the column. This automatically became a selection of two columns (the one I want to select plus the one next to it). I then worked from the bottom of the list up, using ctrl+shift+down button to select all data in that column, starting from the bottom 20 entries - with this, only data in that column was select - it didn't automatically include the next row too, which meant that the merged cell was not within these cells.

I repeated this step, going up the rows ~50 rows at a time, until the selection suddenly became two rows instead, when I was actually just selecting a single row's data. This meant that the merged cell was somewhere in the last 50 rows, and I just went down the list within that selection to check for the merged cell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This only works easily when each cell contains information. It's a pain for sparse columns